# Trying to sort a HashMap<String, List<String>> by list item

Tags: java, algorithm, list, sorting, hashmap

I have a `HashMap<String, List<String>>` and I cannot figure out how to sort it by the 3rd list item. I have tried using a comparator but I can get this to look at the 3rd list item.

The HashMap That I'm using:

```
HashMap<String, List<String>> hmap= new HashMap<String, List<String>>();
List<String> prod1 = new ArrayList<String>();
prod1.add("123456789102");
prod1.add("3.0");
prod1.add("8");
hmap.put("Blue magazine", prod1);
List<String> prod2 = new ArrayList<String>();
prod2.add("123456789102");
prod2.add("2.0");
prod2.add("7");
hmap.put("Pink magazine", prod2);
List<String> prod3 = new ArrayList<String>();
prod3.add("123456789102");
prod3.add("1.0");
prod3.add("6");
hmap.put("Black magazine", prod3);
```

I'm trying to sort it low - high (integers) the 2nd list item. 
so: 6 - 7 - 8

```
    List list = new LinkedList(map.entrySet());
    Collections.sort(list, new Comparator() {
        public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
        return ((Comparable) ((Map.Entry)(o1)).getValue()).compareTo(((Map.Entry)(o2)).getValue());
        }
    });
```

Edit: Added comparator attempt per request.

Comment: What do you mean by 'sorting a HashMap'?

Comment: Don't you mean sorting by the _third_ list item?

Comment: HashMap is unordered. Maybe you should use LinkedHashMap, or TreeMap.

Comment: Attempting to sort a map by value (such that `entrySet().iterator()` gives the desired order) is fundamentally wrong. Do not do it. Instead extract a collection from the map and sort that.

Comment: @Pshemo TreeMap won't work- ordered by Key value

Comment: @ControlAltDel True, that was just wild guess since we don't actually really know what OP wants to achieve and what problem is he facing.

Comment: @Josh, can you specify the o/p that you desire? It is vague to me. Can you only have 3 elements in List? Do you want your Map itself to get sorted ?

Comment: Can you post your Comparator attempt? I'm sure that can be made work, for instance by passing it .entrySet() values (Map.Entry)

Comment: Is this possibly a case of the [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem/66378#66378)? @Josh, what is it you're really trying to do that requires sorting a HashMap?

Comment: @shoover  I'll explain a bit better what I'm trying to accomplish is to have the items in the HashMap be in an order sorted low - high by the 2nd element in the list. I'm trying to do this because I need to present the items 1  at a time in that order.

Comment: @vjar The List will always be 3 elements. o/p for this list I provided would be.
    <"Black magazine" , {"123456789102", "1.0", "6"}> 
    <"Pink magazine", {"123456789102", "2.0", "7"}>
    <"Blue magazine", {"123456789102". "3.0", "8"}>
_Pardon the formatting_

Comment: @Kenney I added my comparator attempt to the post.

Answer (score 1):

An alternative approach that doesn't require access to both `list` and `hmap` within the Comparator and yields a sorted Map:

```
List<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>> list = 
  new LinkedList<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>(hmap.entrySet());

Collections.sort( list, new Comparator<Map.Entry<String,List<String>>>() {
    public int compare( Map.Entry<String,List<String>> o1,
                        Map.Entry<String,List<String>> o2) {
        return o1.getValue().get( 2 ).compareTo(  o2.getValue().get(2) );
    }
});

Map<String, List<String>> result = new LinkedHashMap<String, List<String>>();
for ( Map.Entry<String, List<String>> n : list )
    result.put( n.getKey(), n.getValue() );
```

Answer (score 0):

have you consider to sort your elements when you will be accessing them?

ie

```
for (String key : hmap.keySet().stream()
  .sorted((o1,o2) -> hmap.get(o1).get(2).compareTo(hmap.get(o2).get(2)))
    .collect(Collectors.toList())){
            System.out.println(key);
        }
```

without lambda it will looks like that

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<>(hmap.keySet()); 
Collections.sort(list,new Comparator<String>(){ 
    public int compare(String o1, String o2) {
                        return hmap.get(o1).get(2).compareTo(hmap.get(o2).get(2));
                    } });

for (String key :list ){
   System.out.println(key);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

What I ended up doing to solve this problem is manually sorting and saving the keys to a separate list. Then when I call HashMap items later I just use the keys from the list in order.

```
public List<String> sortProducts(HashMap<String, List<String>> map) {
    HashMap<String, List<String>> preMap = map;
    List<String> sortedNames = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (preMap.size() > 0) {
        Integer currentLowest = 100;
        String currentLowestKey = null;
        for (String key: preMap.keySet()) {
            if (Integer.parseInt(map.get(key).get(2)) < currentLowest) {
                currentLowest = Integer.parseInt(map.get(key).get(2));
                currentLowestKey = key;
            }
        }
        sortedNames.add(currentLowestKey);
        preMap.remove(currentLowestKey);
        currentLowest = 100;
        currentLowestKey = null;
    }
    Collections.reverse(sortedNames);
    return sortedNames;
}
```